# loop through a list of excel sheets and create different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Basically, I have an excel file which I have to read all the sheets apart from the first two. I have tried using a list on the sheet_name parameter, however it returns as invalid sintax. Also tried using this

```
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel('South America services data.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

all_sheets = []
for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
    sheet['sheet'] = name
    sheet = sheet.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('\n')[-1])
    all_sheets.append(sheet)

full_table = pd.concat(all_sheets)
full_table.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

However, I would like to merge them.

I tried using

```
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel('South America services data.xlsx', sheet_name=([2:]))
```

But it gives me a invalid sintax error.
This is the error

```
File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4036\1764796534.py", line 1
    sheets_dict = pd.read_excel('South America services data.xlsx', sheet_name=([2:]))
                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace? or tell us where exactly you're getting the error?

Comment: @Kulasangar just edited with the error.

Comment: What do you mean by - sheet_name=([2:]) ?

Comment: @RajkumarHajgude you can use the number of the sheet, rather than the name, to read it. So I was trying to make a slice starting from the 3rd sheet.

Comment: I mean sheet_name=([2:]) ... you are slicing which list/tuple ? It should be something like - sheet_name=(all_sheets[2:])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using pd.ExcelFile:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile("South America services data.xlsx")

all_sheets = []
for i , name in enumerate(xl.sheet_names):

   if i>=2: # Start reading from the third sheet
       sheet = xl.parse(name)
       sheet['sheet'] = name
       sheet = sheet.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('\n')[-1])
       all_sheets.append(sheet)

full_table = pd.concat(all_sheets)
full_table.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```